# Public void method not working. Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've googled about but still haven't found what I'm looking for. What I want to happen is to get all the comments for a particular image that's been posted.

```
@model IEnumerable<Project1.Models.Picture>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PictureLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Animal Pictures";    
}
@foreach (var picture in Model)
{
    long id = picture.PictureID;
    <div class="picture">
        @Html.ActionLink("Picture", "IndexPic", "Pictures", new { id = picture.PictureID        
}, true)
        <img src="" alt="@picture.File" />
             Posted by @Html.ActionLink(picture.GetUsername(picture.UserID), "Index",  
             "Pictures", new { username = picture.GetUsername(picture.UserID) }, true)
             at @picture.Posted

        @picture.GetComments(picture.PictureID)  **** HERE LIES THE PROBLEM!!!          
    </div>
}
```

The error that is returned is **Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'**

The plan was to get the pictures ID and pass it to a method which would then get all the comments for that picture

```
public void GetComments(long pictureID)
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();
    Picture picture = new Picture();
    //PictureComment comments = new PictureComment();

    var comments = from c in db.PictureComments
                   where pictureID == c.PictureID
                   orderby c.DateTime descending
                   select c;

    foreach (var comment in comments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(picture.GetUsername(comment.UserID));
        Console.WriteLine(comment.Comment);
    }

}
```

I thought at first it was to do with being in a foreach loop, however the **picture.GetUsername()** method works fine.

Are there any SIMPLE work around, I say simple because I am new to c# and not aware of all the concepts/terminology. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which line exactly is erroring out?

Comment: @Selman22 you must have missed the part where he said `because I am new to C# and not aware of all the concepts/terminology` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Console.WriteLine` and your method should return a `MvcHtmlString`.

When you use the `@` symbol before the method in your cshtml file, this means that the result from the method will be written in the resulting html.

this should work:

```
public MvcHtmlString GetComments(long pictureID)
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();
    Picture picture = new Picture();
    //PictureComment comments = new PictureComment();

    var comments = from c in db.PictureComments
                   where pictureID == c.PictureID
                   orderby c.DateTime descending
                   select c;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var comment in comments)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(picture.GetUsername(comment.UserID));
        sb.AppendLine(comment.Comment);
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());

}
```

This would solve your problem, but I suppose you would like to format the comments in some way in your html, so the best thing to do here is to return the list of your comments for a picture.

Then in your cshtml file, use a `foreach` loop to iterate through them, and format them properly with the needed html.

Comment: I was totally unaware of the MvcHtmlString object, I guess it's the whole knowing what to call and when to call it. This has help a lot. Cheers.

Comment: Ok I think I spoke too soon. I'm not sure how I am suppose to loop through the values of the MvcHtmlString? Do i need a foreach loop and use 'foreach (comment in picture.GetComment()) { @Html.Raw(comment) }'

Comment: Actually you wouldn't loop through the `MvcHtmlString` object. You would need to return a `List<CommentObject>` in your method instead, and then loop through the elements in your cshtml. If you need more info I can edit my answer and add an example

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to implement it myself, if not I'll come and bug you some more, hehe. Thanks for the help this far!

Comment: You're welcome ;), if you can't figure it out I'll be happy to help you, good luck!